# Does the relativistic doppler effect breaks symmetries in the Twin Paradox?

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

It is often said that there is no experiment we can make that can determine if we are or aren't moving... this is one of the key aspects of the the Twin Paradox, but, if we accept the constant speed of light postulate, we can determine if we are moving using the relativistic doppler effect. The process can be illustrated with the following thought experiment:

Suppose there are two twins: a stationary twin $T_s$, and a moving one $T_m$. If the moving twin is close to the speed of light in a particular direction $\hat{n}$ within $T_s$'s perspective, then, in $T_m$'s perspective, $T_s$ will be moving in the $-\hat{n}$ direction, also at near-lightspeed. This argument, coupled with the fact that light has the same speed for every inertial observer, suggest the impossibility of determining wich one of the twins is moving in a given moment... But, using spectroscopy, we can effectively decide wether $T_m$ is moving with a simple argument: look for the spectrum of distant stars in both frames. If one observer is the stationary one, their spectrums are shifted to red in both directions, $\hat{n}$ and $-\hat{n}$, due to the expansion of the universe. However, if some of the distant stars have their spectrum shifting to violet in any particular $\hat{n}$ or $-\hat{n}$, then, we can know that $T_m$ is not stationary, and hence, it is moving near lightspeed. If this is taken in account, then there is no need to invoke absolute acceleration to solve the twin paradox: one observer is moving, and the other one is simply not moving, and their proper times get scaled by the appropiate lorentz factors.

Comment: The point is also that the tweens meet again, so at least one has to accelerate, and the acceleration of one of them is what breaks the symmetry, not their velocities which are relative, not absolute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're appealing to the distant stars, but that is picking out the reference frame of "the distant stars", at which point you're not talking about special relativity, you're talking about Robertson-walker cosmololgy

There is a special reference frame in this exact solution to Einstein's equations, the one that is stationary relative to nearby stars.

Comment: another way of thinking about it is "the reference frame where the cosmic microwave background is everywhere isotropic"

Comment: There isn't one frame that is stationary w.r.t do distant stars. Every position has one. We have one, and over in Andromeda its moving at something around 40 fps away from us

Comment: @JEB I'm talking about comoving coordinates and didn't want to get into the scale factor.  I did say "nearby stars"

Answer (score 5):

This only shifts the inertial reference frame from either one of the twins to some distant star. Why should we assume the star is not moving? Indeed, in some frames it is and in others it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is completely irrelevant. It doesn't matter which, if either, twin is moving relative to the distant stars. What counts is the motion of the twins relative to each other. If you have two twins A+B initially at rest relative to each other, and B accelerates away at a given rate and then returns, B will age less than A. That result will be true even if A and B are both initially moving at a speed near to c relative to the distant stars.

Comment: Why the downvote???!!!!!!!!!!!?????????????